# Mockito error "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: mockito, powermockito

Could some one help me how to mock this call?

**Actual code**

```
final ServicesLocal servicesBean = new WSDelegate().getServiceLocal();
```

**here is my mock code**

```
mockDelegate = mock(PortalDelegate.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(PortalDelegate.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockPortalDelegate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `when` for the method invocation as well.

```
ServicesLocal mockServicesLocal = mock(ServicesLocal.class);
when(mockDelegate.getServiceLocal()).thenReturn(mockServicesLocal);
```